# Can't copy file with debugfs command

Tags: ext4, debugfs

I'm playing around with debugfs command:

```
# debugfs -w /dev/sda1 -R "write /etc/passwd /test"
debugfs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Allocated inode: 24
```

But /test is not created:

```
# cat /test
cat: /test: No such file or directory
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Please post the output of `mount | grep /tmp`

Comment: Hi @ArtemS.Tashkinov /tmp is not tmpfs, it's the same file system. Also, I've changed the payload from /tmp/test to /test, same result.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you, I normally never use this command in write mode because doing so can wreak havoc to your FS.